How can I numerically solve this trigonometric equation?
I have tried to use the following.
NSolve[Cos[Pi/2*Cos[\[Theta]]]/Sin[\[Theta]] == 1/Sqrt[2], \[Theta]]

However, I have this error.
NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.

On Mathematica 14.1.0 works fine gives 16 solutions. On Mathematica 13.3.0 try with: NSolve[Cos[Pi/2*Cos[\[Theta]]]/Sin[\[Theta]] == 1/Sqrt[2] &&    0 < \[Theta] < 4 Pi, \[Theta]] ?

There are an infinite number of solutions so you should restrict $\theta$ in some way.  If you choose $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, then there are 2 solutions:  FindRoot[Cos[Pi/2*Cos[\[Theta]]]/Sin[\[Theta]] == 1/Sqrt[2], {{\[Theta], 1}}] and FindRoot[Cos[Pi/2*Cos[\[Theta]]]/Sin[\[Theta]] == 1/Sqrt[2], {{\[Theta], 2}}] if you don't have 14.1.0.

you can also find as many solutions as you want using FindInstance[Cos[Pi/2*Cos[t]]/Sin[t] == 1/Sqrt[2], t, 100]  this finds 100 solutions. Change the number 100 to as large as you want. But you might to wait more.

Manipulate[  Plot[eq   , {\[Theta], -3/2 a \[Pi], 3/2 a \[Pi]}   , PlotRange -> {{-2 a \[Pi] , 2 a \[Pi]}, {-2, 1/2}}   , Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]     , Point[{\[Theta], 0} /.        NSolve[eq && -a \[Pi] < \[Theta] < a \[Pi], \[Theta]]      ]     }   ]  , {{a, 1}, 1, 10}  , SynchronousUpdating -> False  , TrackedSymbols :> All  ]  where eq = Cos[Pi/2*Cos[\[Theta]]]/Sin[\[Theta]] == 1/Sqrt[2];

I suppose you're trying to solve over the reals?:
Solve[Cos[Pi/2*Cos[\[Theta]]]/Sin[\[Theta]] == 1/Sqrt[2], \[Theta], Reals]
(*
{{\[Theta] -> ConditionalExpression[2*Pi*C[1] + 
           Root[{-(1/Sqrt[2]) + Cos[(1/2)*Pi*Cos[#1]]*Csc[#1] & , 
       0.8894396932465515014023450856238683171514493994374724812121`30.102999566398122}], Element[C[1], Reals] && 
           Element[C[1], Integers]]}, 
   {\[Theta] -> ConditionalExpression[2*Pi*C[1] + 
           Root[{-(1/Sqrt[2]) + Cos[(1/2)*Pi*Cos[#1]]*Csc[#1] & , 
       2.2521529603432417370602982976556345670457199999376333397629`30.102999566398122}], Element[C[1], Reals] && 
           Element[C[1], Integers]]}}
*)

Changing Solve to NSolve works, too.
Note that Solve/Reduce/NSolve over the reals checks if the function is periodic. It uses the period to bound the domain, which allows methods for transcendental equations to be used. So there is no need to bound the domain; however, since the period is real, we need to restrict to the Reals. (Doubly periodic equations like Exp[WeierstrassP[x, {1, 2}]]/WeierstrassP[x, {1, 2}] == 6 can be solved over the complexes.)
The solver then uses the period and the roots over the bounded domain to constructs the general solution in terms of an integer parameters (or integer parameters in the doubly periodic case).

Just to illustrate NSolve on domain [0,2$\pi$]. Changed  variable to t just to limit typing:
f[t_] := Cos[Pi/2*Cos[t]]/Sin[t]
p = {t, f[t]} /. NSolve[f[t] == 1/Sqrt[2] && 0 < t < 2 Pi, t];
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, GridLines -> {None, {1/Sqrt[2]}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[p]}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"Solutions:", p}]]



The issue arises because NSolve is primarily designed for solving algebraic equations (polynomial systems or similar), and your equation involves transcendental functions, which often require numerical root-finding techniques rather than symbolic solutions.
can be solved numerically using methods like FindRoot

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
